# Can I handle exception in following way?

Tags: ruby, watir

I am automating a website testing using watir, since server is too busy and bounces a lot, sometimes I get `"Element is no longer valid"` exception.

So will following code work?

```
def click_button(what, how)
 begin
  @browser.button(what=>how).click
  rescue=>exception
  if exception.eql? 'Element is no longer valid'
   click_button(what, how)
  else
   fail_report("Unable to click, '#{exception}'")
  end
 end
end
```

Here `fail_report` is another method that reports fail steps. I can not test it because that exception raises once in 20-25 runs.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Watir automatically relocates elements when they go stale immediately before clicking, so it is unlikely that your code will improve anything.

1. Verify you are doing `require 'watir-webdriver'` and not `require 'watir'`
2. Verify you are using the latest version of watir-webdriver, as I updated the code earlier this year to improve stale element issues.
3. Verify that you have not referenced `Watir.always_locate` anywhere in your code.
4. Automatic relocating doesn't work for elements created from collections. If you are having issues with elements created from collections, let me know, there are a few additional things you can do.

Comment: I did `require 'watir-webdriver'`, and I am using latest version. I did not referenced `Watir.always_locate`. My method clicks on specific element and I pass in arguments identifiers that are unique for `button`

Comment: So, an element becomes stale when the DOM changes. Watir/Selenium elements store an object reference associated with a specific location in the DOM. When it tries to interact with that element, but doesn't see it where it expects to, it throws the stale element exception. This happens when you reload the browser, or any time any information is dynamically removed from the DOM.
I'm curious to see a stack trace; "Element is no longer valid" is an IEDriver message not a Selenium/Watir one, so if it *is a Stale element issue, I'm wondering why it isn't handled by the Ruby code as I'd expect.